# If a function is continued analytically, is the closed integral still zero?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Suppose we have a function $f$ that is analytic in the bottom half-plane i.e. $Im(z)\leq0$. Suppose $g$ is an analytic continuation of $f$ in the upper half-plane.

If we consider an integral over say the circle centered at the origin with some radius $r$ where in the bottom semi-circle we integrate over $f$ and the top semi-circle we integrate over $g$, will the integral still be zero?

Comment: $g$ agrees with $f$ on $f$'s domain, correct?  So why not just integrate over $g$ the entire time, and get $0$?

Comment: Mark is right: by the definition of analytic continuation, the combined function is analytic on its entire domain (in this case, all of $\Bbb C$).

Comment: Alright, thanks!